# Distance of projected point on convex set to any other point in set

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, euclidean-geometry, projection

Is the following statement true? If so, how would I prove it? If not, what is a counterexample?

For any convex set $S\subset \mathbb R^n$, for any point $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $y\in S$,

$$\|\text{proj}_S(x) - y\|_2 \leq \|x-y\|_2$$

where $\text{proj}_S(x)$ is the Euclidean projection of $x$ on $S$

$$\text{proj}_S(x) = \arg\min_{u\in S}\|x-u\|_2^2$$

(For context, I am trying to proofread someone else's proof (not hmwk).)

So far, I have

- been unable to drawn a single picture in which a counterexample holds
- am playing around with the following three properties, with $x_s = \text{proj}_S(x)$:

1)   $(x-x_s)^T(y-x_s) \leq 0$ (normal cone / optimality condition)

2) $\|x-x_s\|\leq\|x-y\|$ (distance to projection always closest)

3) $\|x-x_s\|^2 + \|x-y\|^2 \geq |(x-x_s)^T(y-x_s)|$ (completing the square)

I feel like I'm close!

Comment: What's your definition of the projection onto $S$ of $x$?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I just mean the standard Euclidean projection in $\mathbb R^n$, which I clarified now in the problem statement. Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: One definition of the projection is $\arg \min_{y \in S} \| x-y \|$.  So, you'll need to figure out what exactly you're allowed to use in solving this problem.

Comment: My guess is that the inequality is indeed true and it reduces to a property of triangles. Prove by contradiction.Work in the plane determined by $x,y  $ and $proj_S(x)$  and draw a perpendicular from $x$ to the line joining $y$ and  $proj_S(x)$. I don't have a detailed argument yet. The only thing you have to make sure is that the perpendicular meets the line joining $y$ and  $proj_S(x)$ between these two points (so that this point lies in $S$).

Comment: Geometrically I think you're right, @KaviRamaMurthy. Took some effort to plug in the details, but it seems to work out fairly well!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this might have been much easier than I thought. Assume the contradiction:

$$\|x_s-y\| > \|x-y\|.$$

Then expanding out, we have

$$A: x_s^Tx_s - 2x_s^Ty > x^Tx-2x^Ty$$

Now let's insert the normal cone constraint

$$B: (x−x_s)^T(y−x_s)= x_s^Tx_s - x_s^T(y+x) + x^Ty\leq 0$$

add  $A + 2\times B$ and simplify

$$x_s^Tx_s + x^Tx - 2x_s^Tx = \|x_s-x\|^2_2 < 0$$

which of course is a contradiction.

In other words, the normal cone constraint alone is  equivalent to the original statement.